# Apple iOS Developer Enterprise: Clearness of installation process

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, installation

We have an app distributed in the company according to [Apple iOS Developer Enterprise Program](http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/). We find the installation/updating process is unclear for the users.

The issue is that when a user click on 
**itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=???.plist** like URL, the browser shows the message that the installation is about to begin. However, once a user confirms the installation to start, visually nothing happens afterwards. So a user can't see if the app is actually being installed, until he/she goes to the home screen.

Does anybody have an idea on how to bring more clarity to this process for the user?

Comment: Accept from explain then what is going to happen, no. The process is as is.